# How to check if the keys of two dictionaries are the same

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am trying to write a python function to compare the keys in two dictionaries. I am doing this to check that the keys in the dictionary that for a particular json are not ever changed and remain consistent.

I will have one dictionary stored in the python coding and other one that I will do a GET request to get hold of.

Can anyone help me on how to go about doing this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dict.viewkeys` it returns a set like view object:

```
>>> {'a':4, 'b':2}.viewkeys() == {'a':0, 'b':1}.viewkeys()
True
```

You can't rely on `dict.keys` in py2.x because it returns a list and the order of keys can be arbitrary.

```
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c'] == ['a', 'c', 'b']    #same keys, but not equal
False
>>> set(['a', 'b', 'c']) == set(['a', 'c', 'b']) #sets compare fine
True
```

On py3.x use `dict.keys()`.

Comment: This is 2.7+ (and just `dict.keys()` in 3+). This also has the advantage of being able to do an `XOR` operation using the `^` operator (to see the "difference"). +1

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
{'a':4, 'b':2}.keys() == {'a':0, 'b':1}.keys()
```